# Edge smoothing while keeping features such as corners

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, vector, smoothing

I am trying to smooth the edges of a polygon. This is for a mapping application that allows a user to zoom in and out. At a high zoom I don't need all the detail so I smooth the polygon to reduce the number of points. I simply iterate though all the points and remove any point that is within X distance from the last. Where X is appropriately 1 pixel on the resulting screen.

This seems to work great, except in a few cases. For example, if a user zooms in, I enlarge the vector, while loading the detail asynchronously. While the extra detail is being loaded, the user sees something like what's in the below image:

[image: Enlarged vector image showing the problem]

The square vector polygons have had their corners somewhat inadvertently rounded.

What I'm looking for, is a smoothly, or resizing algorithm, that will reduce the number of points to draw a polygon, whilst maintaining some of the features, such as the corners.

Comment: Why do any of those polygons have more than 4 widely-spaced points?

Comment: These polygons are US Counties, and not all are simple squares. I just picked a area you could see the problem. However, the data that defines the counties (as provided by the Census Bureau) have straight edges with many points.

Hopefully a smoothing algorithm can remove these useless points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like the [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm.

It can be used to simplify poly-lines by removing the points that don't change the overall shape "too much" (where a tolerance value controls what's meant by "too much").

I would expect that this would remove points along the "straight-ish" part of a poly-line, while leaving the sharp features (like corners) intact.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might check the angle formed by the two lines on either side of the point, and only remove the point if the angle is below a specified threshold.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I was hoping for a more formal algorithm instead of rolling my own.

Comment: @bramp I see.  Shall I delete this?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, I don't know what the StackOverflow etiquette is, but I don't mind if it stays or is deleted. Perhaps someone will enlighten us with a formal algorithm based on your suggestion.